# Count on mysql GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I would like to count the number of unique days each user visits my site using the following two (simplified) tables:

```
Table: Users
+--------------+------------------+
| Field        | Type             |
+--------------+------------------+
| userid       | int(10)          |
| firstname    | varchar(50)      |
| lastname     | varchar(50)      |
+--------------+------------------+

Table: Visitors
+--------------+------------------+
| Field        | Type             |
+--------------+------------------+
| visitorid    | int(10)          |
| userid       | int(10)          |
| visitdate    | timestamp        |
+--------------+------------------+
```

First I am grouping by `DATE(visitdate)` to group the records by date.
Then I am grouping by `userid` to group and count the number of days each user has visited.

My query for this is:

```
SELECT count(userid) as count, userid, firstname, lastname FROM 
    (SELECT users.userid, firstname, lastname, DATE(`visitdate`) AS dateonly FROM 
    visitors JOIN users ON visitors.userid = users.userid 
    GROUP BY DATE(`visitdate`)) b 
GROUP BY userid ORDER BY count DESC
```

However this is giving an incorrect count which is verified when I simply add a `WHERE` clause to restrict the userid. The following query gives the correct count for a single user.

```
SELECT count(userid) as count, userid, firstname, lastname FROM 
    (SELECT users.userid, firstname, lastname, DATE(`visitdate`) AS dateonly FROM 
    visitors JOIN users ON visitors.userid = users.userid 
    WHERE users.userid = 167
    GROUP BY DATE(`visitdate`)) b 
GROUP BY userid ORDER BY count DESC
```

Obviously I've got it wrong -any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question right I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT u.userid, u.firstname, u.lastname, COUNT(DISTINCT CAST(v.visitdate AS DATE)) AS visits
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN visitors v ON v.userid = u.userid 
GROUP BY u.userid, u.firstname, u.lastname
```

This will show you the userid, firstname, lastname and count of distinct visitdates for each user (or 0 if there are no visits as it uses a left join to include users that lack items in the visitors table).

Comment: Since `visitdate` is a `timestamp` and this is a log of pages visited, I need to group on `visitdate` first so that I get one entry for each day the user visited. That is why the `group by` within a `group by` in my code.

Comment: @mseifert Ah, I missed that; but I think you could be able to just cast the timestamp to date in order to get it right, I changed the query, please try it.

Comment: This does indeed work, thank you. Can you venture a guess why my two statements in the original question produce different results for `userid = 167`? I'd like to find the fault in the logic to understand mysql better.

Comment: @mseifert If I were to guess your first query should only have returned a single row with a count applied to the entire set; this is what MySQL should do if you omit columns from the group by - but maybe I'm misinterpreting the query - I don't have any MySQL server available to test.

Comment: Ah, the solution was that I left out `userid` in the `Group By` in the first query. Thanks!